# Unexplained behavior boost::scoped_lock

Tags: c++, boost, boost-mutex, scoped-lock

I am wrote on C++ multithread TCP server,  for synchronization using boost:scoped_lock

After connecting to server client freezes.

in gdb i saw more threads in pthread_kill after call boost::mutex::lock

```
(gdb) info thread

277 Thread 808779c00 (LWP 245289330/xgps)  0x0000000802579d5c in poll () at poll.S:3
  276 Thread 808779800 (LWP 245289329/xgps)  0x00000008019799bc in pthread_kill () from /lib/libthr.so.3
  275 Thread 808779400 (LWP 245289328/xgps)  0x00000008019799bc in pthread_kill () from /lib/libthr.so.3
 .....
  246 Thread 808c92800 (LWP 245289296/xgps)  0x00000008019799bc in pthread_kill () from /lib/libthr.so.3
  245 Thread 808643800 (LWP 245289295/xgps)  0x00000008019799bc in pthread_kill () from /lib/libthr.so.3
  244 Thread 808643400 (LWP 245289294/xgps)  0x00000008019799bc in pthread_kill () from /lib/libthr.so.3
  243 Thread 806c8f400 (LWP 245289292/xgps)  0x00000008019799bc in pthread_kill () from /lib/libthr.so.3
  242 Thread 808643000 (LWP 245286262/xgps)  0x00000008019799bc in pthread_kill () from /lib/libthr.so.3
  241 Thread 808c92400 (LWP 245289288/xgps)  0x00000008019799bc in pthread_kill () from /lib/libthr.so.3



[Switching to thread 205 (Thread 80863a000 (LWP 245289251/xgps))]#0  0x00000008019799bc in pthread_kill () from /lib/libthr.so.3
(gdb) where
#0  0x00000008019799bc in pthread_kill () from /lib/libthr.so.3
#1  0x0000000801973cfc in pthread_getschedparam () from /lib/libthr.so.3
#2  0x00000008019782fc in pthread_mutex_getprioceiling () from /lib/libthr.so.3
#3  0x000000080197838b in pthread_mutex_lock () from /lib/libthr.so.3
#4  0x0000000000442b2e in boost::mutex::lock (this=0x803835f10) at mutex.hpp:62
#5  0x0000000000442c36 in boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex>::lock (this=0x7fffe7334270) at lock_types.hpp:346
#6  0x0000000000442c7c in unique_lock (this=0x7fffe7334270, m_=@0x803835f10) at lock_types.hpp:124
#7  0x0000000000466e31 in XDevice::getDeviceIMEI (this=0x803835e20) at /home/xgps_app/device.cpp:639
#8  0x000000000049071f in XDevicePool::get_device (this=0x7fffffffd9c0, device_imei=868683024674230) at /home/xgps_app/pool_devices.cpp:351
```

Code at line device.cpp:639

```
IMEI 
XDevice::getDeviceIMEI()
{
    try {
        boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(cn_mutex);
        return  device_imei;
    }
    catch (std::exception &e )
    {
        cout << " ERROR in getDeviceIMEI " << e.what() << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Code in pool_device

```
XDevicePtr  
XDevicePool::get_device(IMEI device_imei)
{
    XDevicePtr device;
    unsigned int i = 0;

    while(i < this->devices.size())
    {
        device = devices[i]; 
        if (device->getDeviceIMEI() == device_imei) {
            LOG4CPLUS_DEBUG(logger,  "XDevicePool::get_device found!");
            return device;
        }
        i++;
    }   
    device.reset();
    return device;
}

XDevicePtr 
XDevicePool::get_device_mt(IMEI device_imei)
{
    try 
    {
        boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(pool_mutex);

    }
    catch (std::exception & e)
    {
        LOG4CPLUS_ERROR(logger,  "XDevicePool::get_device error! " << e.what());
    } 
//  boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(pool_mutex);
    return get_device(device_imei); 
}
```

Why after call to mutex lock thread terminating?
I think dead lock  not reason for that behavior
Please help!

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple locks.

Whenever you have multiple locks that can be required simultaneously you need to obtain them in a fixed order, to avoid dead-locking.

It seems likely that you have such a deadlock occurring. See Boost Thread's free function `boost::lock` http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.lock_functions.lock_multiple for help acquiring multiple lock in reliable order.

You will also want to know about `std::defer_lock`.

---

Other than this, there might be interference from `fork` in multi-threaded programs. I think it's beyond the scope now to explain, unless you are indeed using `fork` in your process

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr `pthread_kill` is likely a red herring.**

> Why after call to mutex lock thread terminating?

It doesn't. Your threads have not been terminated (as evidenced by them still appearing on `info thread`).

You seem to assume that `pthread_kill` kills the current thread. In fact, what `pthread_kill` does is send a signal to another thread. And even the sending is optional (if `sig=0`).

See the [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_kill.3.html) for further details.